# React native cannot start js server properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, nodejs-server

I have trying to run a newly created react-native project with react-native init command
when using react-native run-android, it has the issue of starting the js server as the path to user profile "C:\User\Dan" is not recognized. 
I'm guessing this issue is due to the fact that my profile folder has a spacing of "Dan Tan". 
But I have no idea how to work around this. 
It has no issue starting the android emulator right after.

Operating System: Windows 10
npm : 6.9.0
node :10.16.3
[image]

Comment: are you the same error on react-native start?

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari no errors on react-native start.
I get Running Metro Bundler on port 8081
Looking for Js file in c:\rtest\AwesomeProject and Loading dependency graph , done. I believe this is normal.

Comment: So use the react-native start for running server

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari Error persist when i run "start" in a command prompt and "run-android" after in 2 separate cmds . https://imgur.com/a/wuJZlbI i have uploaded screen shot of the error

Comment: cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ../ && react-native run-android

Comment: Please use above command

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari When executing ./gradlew clean , it says '.' is not recognised as a command, am i missing something?

Comment: use without dot "gradlew clean"

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari now it say '/gradlew' is not a recognized command.

Comment: just run gradlew clean

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari gradlew clean worked(modified item). But  same existing problem when running ../ followed by react-native run-android after.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari I found the fix which was the naming of the user profile. Renamed it and edited registry. At least it runs properly now. thanks for the help